# Calculate running balance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found below query to calculate running balance.

```
SELECT intId, varName, decAmt, charCrDr, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN charCrDr = 'c' THEN
               decAmt
           ELSE
              decAmt * -1
           END )
           OVER (PARTITION BY varName ORDER BY intId) As decTotal
FROM #Temp;
```

I would like to know what it means by else condition

Comment: That just determines whether you are adding `decAmt` or subtracting it.

Comment: decAmt * -1 will do what exactly behind SQL?

Comment: What I want to know is if there is a function in SQL as -1 or similar? What if we do -2?

Comment: @DeEDEe . . . It multiplies the value by "-1".  If you had "-2", it would multiple the value by "-2".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the whole question seems to be about multiplying with minus 1.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crude way of doing the SUM OR DIFFERENCE operation:
Here what you are trying to do is to find the difference for decAmt like below:

```
decAmt(where charCrDr = 'c') - decAmt
```

Answer (score 0):

`decAmt * -1` multiplies the value of decAmt by -1 so that if it is positive it becomes negative number if it is negative it becomes positive number

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's about the Credit(Cr) and Debit(Dr). The running balance is:

```
sum of Credits - (sum of Debits)
```

So the `decAmt` for debit records (in the `ELSE` part, that is `WHEN charCrDr != 'c'`) are multiplied by -1 to maintain the above formula.

Good Luck.